# Need a video editing software for piecing together clips from YouTube/twitch

Tags: video-editing

Basically I have a group that plays Smash Bros and Rivals of Aether, I want a software that I can use to cut and put together clips from their tournament matches (with premission of the original streamers of course), preferably free but if I need to pay I'll pay.

Answer (score 3):

There's OpenShot, an open source application that runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

It's very versatile and relatively easy to use

[OpenShot Video Editor](https://www.openshot.org/)

Comment: It seems that openshot reencode the video. Anything simpler? Took 3 hours to merge 2 videos totalling 40 minutes

Answer (score 1):

A couple of [Python](https://www.python.org/) based components that should be able to do the job nicely for you:

- [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) a command line interface to download YouTube videos given the URL
- [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) a python video manipulation module that uses FFMPEG, *(which it downloads and installs for you if necessary on first use),* behind the scenes to cut, stitch, etc., videos.

These items are all free, *gratis & Open Source*, and cross platform.